# How to run a file using VisualBasicScript (.vbs)

Tags: file, vbscript

How can I run a file with VisualBasicScript (.vbs)?

The file is 'file.bat' and it's located in the same dir as the .vbs.

Comment: @YourComputerHelpZ - you are a getting lot of great answers. Maybe you should explain what is your objective. Open the 'file.bat' and then do what? Display its contents in a message box, edit some text, run the batch file, etc?

Comment: By saying "open", do you mean "launch"/"execute"?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> yes i want to run it.

Then try this:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "file.bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

See many examples on technet [Script Center Script Repository](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/default.mspx?mfr=true).

A simple example is [*Select and Ping Computers Using a Text File*](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/default.mspx?mfr=true):

```
On Error Resume Next

Const ForReading = 1

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\scripts\servers.txt", ForReading)

strComputers = objTextFile.ReadAll
objTextFile.Close

arrComputers = Split(strComputers, vbCrLf)
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

For Each strComputer In arrComputers

    strCommand = "%comspec% /c ping -n 3 -w 1000 " & strComputer
    Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec(strCommand)
    strText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadAll
    If Instr(strText, "Reply") > 0 Then

    ' =====================================================================
    ' Insert your code here
    ' =====================================================================

        Set objWMIService = GetObject _
            ("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
        Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
            ("Select * From Win32_OperatingSystem")
        For Each objItem In ColItems
            Wscript.Echo strComputer & ": " & objItem.Caption
        Next


    Else
        Wscript.Echo strComputer & " could not be reached."
    End If

Next
```

Comment: hmmm.. can't really find easily what i'm looking for.

Comment: The first answer is the best

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711216(VS.71).aspx)

Usage to open file:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(".\File.bat", ForReading)
```

Comment: see above, that will get you as file as opening a file, In this case it is being opened for reading, you can also specify for writing or appending.

Comment: Note ForWriting will overwrite any current contents.

Comment: My bad, you need to locally define the const ForReading, above edited. Please clarify, "I would like .bat"

Comment: Does it give you an exception? What exactly do you want to do with the file when you open it? Given that it is a bat file, do you actually want to "run" the batch file?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFileInfo(filePath)
    dim fso, fileObj, outMsg
    set fso = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    set fileObj = fso.getfile(filePath)
    outMsg = ""
    outMsg = outMsg & " Created: " & fileObj.DateCreated & vbcrlf
    outMsg = outMsg & " Last Accessed: " & fileObj.DateLastAccessed & vbcrlf
    outMsg = outMsg & " Last Modified: " & fileObj.DateLastModified & vbcrlf
    outMsg = outMsg & " File Type: " & fileObj.Type & vbcrlf
    if fileObj.attributes and 0 then
        outMsg = outMsg & " File Attributes: Normal File"
    else
        outMsg = outMsg & " File Attributes: "
        if fileObj.attributes and 1 then
            outMsg = outMsg & "Read Only "
        end if
        if fileObj.attributes and 2 then
            outMsg= outMsg & "Hidden "
        end if
        if fileObj.attributes and 4 then
            outMsg= outMsg & "System "
        end if
        if fileObj.attributes and 8 then
            outMsg= outMsg & "Volume "
        end if
        if fileObj.attributes and 16 then
            outMsg= outMsg & "Directory "
        end if
        if fileObj.attributes and 32 then
            outMsg= outMsg & "Archive "
        end if
        if fileObj.attributes and 1024 then
            outMsg= outMsg & "Link "
        end if
        if fileObj.attributes and 2048 then
            outMsg= outMsg & "Compressed "
        end if
    end if
    set fileObj = nothing
    set fso = nothing
    getFileInfo = outMsg
end function
```

Comment: uhmmmm... i just want to open it, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Even simplier
This code works for all OS, I tried it in Windows 10 and it works so well:
Try it by yourself :)

```
Function BrowseForFile()
  BrowseForFile = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec( _
  "mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=f>" & _
  "<script>resizeTo(0,0);f.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')" & _
  ".GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(f.value);close();</script>""" _
  ).StdOut.ReadLine()
End Function
```

Answer (score -3):

Jamb Code:

```
jamb(run) "%PWD%\File.bat" & display box(small) with $OUTPUT
```

VBS Code:

```
set runFile (".\file.bat")
mode console
msgbox (runFile)
```

Comment: I am not sure this answers the question