# How do I open a file with VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

How do I open a file with VBScript, as if the user had double clicked the file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open files using VisualBasicScript (.vbs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956362/open-files-using-visualbasicscript-vbs)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\Program Files\my_html_files\file.htm""")
```

And check the application registered with the .htm extension (probably `IExplore.exe`), in these registry keys:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.htm
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\htmlfile\shell\open\command
HKCU\Software\Classes\.htm
```

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("C:\\Program Files\\my_html_files\\file.htm")
```

Comment: file.htm exist but when I run the script I get the message that the system cant find the specific file?

Comment: Try to put script file in the same folder as target html file, remove the absolute path and try again

Comment: I cant because I must to run it only from this PATH

Comment: Backslashes aren't special characters in VBScript, so they don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774148(VS.85).aspx

```
<script language="VBScript">
function fnShellExecuteVB()
    dim objShell

    set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    objShell.ShellExecute "notepad.exe", "", "", "open", 1

    set objShell = nothing
end function
</script>
```

Comment: can you please give me example how to open the C:\Program Files\my_html_files\file.html file
thx

Comment: I get the error message: 
ActiveX component cant create objecte:'shell_application' ?

Comment: It should be "Shell.Application", not "shell.Shell_Application".