# Call Ruby from a VBScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vbscript

Hey I have been working with `ruby` and `vbscript` lately. There is a scenario where I need to call a ruby script from another `vbscript` and I am stuck there. I tried this code,

```
Set newobj = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
obj = newobj.Run("ruby E:\rubyfile.rb > D:\newdoc.txt",1,true)
```

but the ruby script is not giving the result. Am I doing it right or is there some other way to do it? 
If the ruby script is executed separately then the results are generated, so the problem is not with the ruby script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a file using VisualBasicScript (.vbs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956362/how-to-run-a-file-using-visualbasicscript-vbs)

Comment: Better match for possible duplciate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/28088237/692942

Comment: I would suggest before posting anymore questions go and read [ask]. This is just another duplicate of a question that's been asked time after time. It takes a minute to lookup the [`WScript.Shell` `Run()` method in the MSDN Library documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a shell (`%comspec% /c`) to get a shell's feature like `>` redirection. So change

```
obj = newobj.Run("ruby E:\rubyfile.rb > D:\newdoc.txt",1,true)
```

to

```
nRet = newobj.Run("%comspec% /c ruby E:\rubyfile.rb > D:\newdoc.txt",1,true)
```

(Study the [docs for .Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx) to see the reason for `nRet` instead of `obj` and spend a thought on the lousy-ness of the name "newobj")

Comment: hey, suppose i want to pass variables as my parameters, is it possible?
example: 
newva =  10
obj = newobj.Run("%comspec% /c ruby E:\rubyfile.rb  newva > D:\newdoc.txt", 1, true) ? is this possible? 
because the variable which i pass as parameter is changing frequently so i cannot pass a argument to the function.

Comment: Carbon copy of yet another duplicate answer you've given before - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28088558/692942