# Call Ruby script from a VBSript?

Tags: ruby, vbscript

It is possible to run ruby script from VBScript? I want only to run ruby script from VBS, how to do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113881/call-ruby-from-a-vbscript

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for!