# Output of Ruby script as variable in VBScript

Tags: ruby, vbscript

I need to run ruby script in VBScipt. I have a code:

```
Set newobj = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
vbsInterpreter = "cscript.exe"
nRet = newobj.Run("%comspec% /c c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Puppet Labs\\Puppet\\sys\\ruby\\bin\\ruby.exe c:\\scr.rb")
```

The ruby script output is `puts "Directory is empty"` and now I want that nRet was the string "Directory is empty". Running VBScript I get

> C:>cscript test.vbs Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.6
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1996-2001. All rights reserved.
>
> 0

Why 0? How to make the ruby script output the VBScript output?

Answer (score 0):

Your question (and especially the sub question "Why 0") shows that you prefere code (to copy without understanding) to advice (like reading the Docs or think about variable (names)). [evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39114857/603855)
So here is code:

```
type ..\rb\44245994.rb
puts "Why didn't you study the docs for .RUN (and .Exec)?"
5.times do
  puts "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
end
ARGV.each {|a| p a}
puts "Done."
exit 14
```

44245994.vbs:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS  : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sRuby : sRuby    = "C:\Program Files\Ruby-2.1\bin\ruby.exe"
Dim oSH   : Set oSH  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim sCmd  : sCmd     = Join(Array( _
    qq(sRuby) _
  , qq(goFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\rb\44245994.rb")) _
  , "pi" _
  , qq("1, 2, 3") _
))
WScript.Echo "sCmd:", sCmd
WScript.Echo "Stdout of execee:"  , oSH.Exec(sCmd).StdOut.ReadAll()
WScript.Echo "exit code of runee:", oSH.Run(sCmd, 0, True)

Function qq(s)
  qq = """" & s & """"
End Function
```

output:

```
cscript 44245994.vbs
sCmd: "C:\Program Files\Ruby-2.1\bin\ruby.exe" "E:\work\proj\soa\44245994\rb\44245994.rb" pi "1, 2, 3"
Stdout of execee: Why didn't you study the docs for .RUN (and .Exec)?
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
"pi"
"1, 2, 3"
Done.

exit code of runee: 14
```

Comment: Thanks, but I use only this part of code ;)

`Option Explicit


Dim goFS  : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim sRuby : sRuby    = "c:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\sys\ruby\bin\ruby.exe"

Dim oSH   : Set oSH  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


oSH.Exec("""c:\Program Files (x86)\Puppet Labs\Puppet\sys\ruby\bin\ruby.exe"" ""c:\src.rb""").StdOut.ReadAll()`